# VBA Selenium Chrome struggling to identify button element

Tags: excel, vba, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to add an action on my VBA script to click download for an instagram video.
The url for the button is here https://snapinsta.app/  and is just the download button next to the url box.
The HTML code defines it as:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-get flex-center"><i class="icon icon-download"></i>Download</button>
```

My code to run this is as follows:

```
Option Explicit
Dim ch As Selenium.ChromeDriver

Public Sub Video_Download()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ch = New Selenium.ChromeDriver
Set ws = ActiveSheet

Dim FindBy As New Selenium.By


    
Dim i As Integer
For i = 20 To 20    

ch.Start baseUrl:="https://snapinsta.app"
    ch.Get "/"
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:06"))

    
    ch.Window.Maximize
    ch.FindElementByName("url").SendKeys ActiveSheet.Range("B" & i).Value
    ch.FindElementByClass("btn btn-get flex-center").submit
```

Cell B20 returns the valid address - the code just encounters an error on the last line - that compound class lines are not permitted:

[image]

I have tried various options as define by type/id etc but have not been able to get it to work.
Can anyone suggest a solution please?

I am expecting the download button to activate and to download the url.